# Morse Code (Ohaver Scheme) Python

Tags: python

Doing a project of a morse code here and need some help with it.

How does it work?

1. Input message : PUEL
2. Morse Code    : .--...-..-.. 4314 (the numbers refer to code length based on the numbers of dot and dashes for each letters in input message (seperated by " ")
3. Access morse code string in reverse to encode. (4314 <-- access the string here)
4. Convert dots and dashes back to text using reverse string of numbers (refer to 3)
5. Result : PERL

The main codes that I made (important ones):

```
## this is my morseDictionary 
# convert from text to morsecode.
morseDictionary = {
    "A" : ".-",
    "B" : "-...",
    "C" : "-.-.",
    "D" : "-..",
    "E" : ".",
    "F" : "..-.",
    "G" : "--.",
    "H" : "....",
    "I" : "..",
    "J" : ".---",
    "K" : "-.-",
    "L" : ".-..",
    "M" : "--",
    "N" : "-.",
    "O" : "---",
    "P" : ".--.",
    "Q" : "--.-",
    "R" : ".-.",
    "S" : "...",
    "T" : "-",
    "U" : "..-",
    "V" : "...-",
    "W" : ".--",
    "X" : "-..-",
    "Y" : "-.--",
    "Z" : "--..",
    "_" : "..--",
    "," : ".-.-",
    "." : "---.",
    "?" : "----"

}

 # reverse dictionary of morseDictionary
 # convert from morse to text.
 morseReverse = dict((value,key) for (key,value) in morseDictionary.items())


# convert the message from string to morse code. Ex : .--...--- 2322
def convertMorseM(string):
  string1 = ""
  string2 = ""
  codecombine = ""
  code_length = ""
  final_string = ""
  for letter in string:
      string1 = morseDictionary[letter]
      string2 = str(len(morseDictionary[letter]))
      code_length = code_length + string2
      codecombine = codecombine + string1
      final_string = codecombine + " " + code_length
  return final_string

# where the encoding of morse applies (problem)
def encodeMessage(message):
  final_string = " "
  index = 0
  string = " "

  for items in message[::-1]:
      if items.isspace():
          return final_string
      string = morseReverse[(message[:index + int(items)])]
      final_string = final_string + string
      index = index + int(items)

  # main function
  def main():
    print("Welcome to morse code converter !")
    print("Enter your message to see your awesome message translated to a morse code !")
    message = input("Enter a message : ")
    message = message.upper()

    # function calling for all necessary items
    # numbers of characters in the message.
    codenum = str(len(message))

    # converts into morse code with code length etc : .--...--- 2322
    convMessage = convertMorseM(message)

    ## gets the code length of the string
    codLength = codeLength(message)

    ## encodeds the convMessage starting from behind <--
    encodeM = encodeMessage(convMessage)


    ## display all data here
    print("Your message : " + message)
    print("Morse code convert : " + convMessage)
    print("Word length : " + codenum)
    print("Code Length for each letter : " + codLength)
    print(" ")
    print("Encoded Message : " + encodeMessage)

    print(" ")
```

tried this code and an error occured :

```
   File "MorseCode.py", line 41, in encodeMessage
   string = morseRev[message[:index + int(items)]]
   KeyError : '.--...-'
```

I need help regarding this problem. Thank you

Comment: There's a bug in your program, you're trying to look up '.--...-' in your dictionary but your dictionary has just individual letters, not the whole message.  You haven't shown us how you called your functions, so it's a little difficult to help any further without more information.

Comment: message = input("Enter a message : ")
 message = message.upper()  this is for input for the message     convMessage = convertMorseM(message)   for convertMorseM                       encodeM = encodeMessage(convMessage)  for encodeMessage                   and use the variables in print for output i hope u can read this :<

Comment: Also, I suggest you use lists, the built in `join` function, and other built-ins like `reverse` in order to simplify your code.  Also, you can write '+=' in python: rather than `x = x + y`, simplify to `x += y`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your program as written is overly complicated so it's difficult for me to debug it for you.  It was easier for me to rewrite it so you can see how to do what you're trying to do in a much simpler way.  Starting with the input, I think you really only need three things:

1. The input as a series of dits and dahs (you don't need the spaces here)
2. The reversed lengths
3. The inverted morse dictionary (from dit-dahs to characters)

To get (1):

```
input = 'PUEL'
input_morse_str = ''.join([morse_dictionary[c] for c in input])
```

To get (2):

Here there's no need for strings (you are doing `str` and then `int` in your example program, you may as well just leave them as ints):

```
reversed_lengths = list(reversed([len(morse_dictionary[c]) for c in input]))
```

Finally, you also want the inverted dictionary for the morse code (3):

```
inverse_dictionary = {value: key for (key, value) in morse_dictionary.items()}
```

With those three data structures, you can go ahead and decode:

```
output = ''; i = 0
for l in reversed_lengths:
    output += inverse_dictionary[input_morse_str[i:i+l]]
    i += l
print output
```

Here's everything put together in one working script (with input hardcoded):

```
$ cat morse_reverse.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

morse_dictionary = {
    "A" : ".-",   "B" : "-...", "C" : "-.-.", "D" : "-..",  "E" : ".",
    "F" : "..-.", "G" : "--.",  "H" : "....", "I" : "..",   "J" : ".---",
    "K" : "-.-",  "L" : ".-..", "M" : "--",   "N" : "-.",   "O" : "---", 
    "P" : ".--.", "Q" : "--.-", "R" : ".-.",  "S" : "...",  "T" : "-",
    "U" : "..-",  "V" : "...-", "W" : ".--",  "X" : "-..-", "Y" : "-.--",
    "Z" : "--..", "_" : "..--", "," : ".-.-", "." : "---.", "?" : "----"
}

inverse_dictionary = {value: key for (key, value) in morse_dictionary.items()}


input = 'PUEL'
input_morse = [morse_dictionary[c] for c in input]
input_morse_str = ''.join(input_morse)
reversed_lengths = list(reversed([len(c) for c in input_morse]))

output = ''
i = 0
for l in reversed_lengths:
    output += inverse_dictionary[input_morse_str[i:i+l]]
    i += l
print output
$ python morse_reverse.py
PERL
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer is downvoted?  I did my best to provide a learning opportunity for a question which wasn't very well phrased.  I showed the OP how to simply the logic, use more pythonic idioms (and python built-ins), and even provided a working solution.  Oh well.  So much for the time I spent trying to help.

Comment: so for those code length (string numbers) you seperated them and put them into a list? and access the list in reverse? P.S : who downvoted your answer?

Comment: Check out the way that list comprehensions work in python.  `[f(x) for x in iterable]` creates a list where each item in the output is a function of an item in the input.  So, `[len(c) for c in input_morse]` is a list of the lengths of the items in `input_morse`.   Try out the code I wrote for you, add `print` statements to look at the data structures where you need to.

Re who downvoted me: idk maybe the same person who downvoted your question.  Your question wasn't phrased very well, it took me a long time to figure out what you were trying to achieve.  Anyway, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks it does help me a lot :D. But another question, can i pass the lists as parameters in a function? Etc : encode = encodeM(reverse_lengths)             My code at least needs 1 function  (and im planning to use the line output = ' ' to line output as its method )

Comment: Of course you can pass lists as parameters.  But you should learn to use the python interpreter to answer that kind of question for yourself.  Good luck.